# Can the Sabatier reaction power a vehicle?

Tags: automotive-engineering, chemical-engineering, energy, energy-storage

The [Sabatier reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabatier_reaction) converts CO<sub>2</sub> to methane. Can a vehicle that burns methane recover it (at least some part) from the exhaust gases via the Sabatier reaction? I am interested to know how this would be implemented, and whether such a vehicle has ever been built or prototyped.

Comment: Draw a pfd of the supposed engine, and then ask your question yourself.

Answer (score 14):

According to Wikipedia:

> It [Sabatier reaction ] involves the reaction of hydrogen with carbon dioxide at elevated temperatures (optimally 300–400 °C) and pressures in the presence of a nickel catalyst to produce methane and water. $$ CO_2 + 4H_2 \rightarrow CH_4 + H_2O + \text{Energy} $$

as you can see from the previous chemical reaction, to obtain 1 KMole of $CH_4$ you should have 4 Kmole of Hydrogen as reactants and a reaction medium of 300–400 °C (with god knows how much of catalyst you need).

Comparing to a regular vehicle internal combustion engine running on Methane:

- Hydrogen is not available in ambient air to the degree that could
  allow a sustainable Sabatier reaction (it's not Oxygen), meaning you need a
  separate Hydrogen tank along side with your engine (not to mention
  the explosive nature of Hydrogen).
- Preheating the reactants to 300–400 °C would require an external
  heating system if done using hydrocarbon fuel, it would require an
  additional combustion chamber and a heat exchanger.
- Higher heating value of Methane = 889 kJ/Mole and HHV of Hydrogen =
  286 kJ/Mole (Wikipedia), so theoretically speaking, the Sabatier reaction
  would provide you with 1 Mole of CH4 having heating value of 889 kJ by
  supplying the reactor 4 Moles of H2 that had a heating value of 4 *
  286 = 1144 kJ !!
- The resulting Methane and water have a ratio of 1:1, introducing this
  mixture with this amount of water to the
  combustion chamber will give you a VERY low efficiency combustion
  process, So naturally you need a separation mechanism to lower water content as possible before entering combustion chamber.

> So has anyone researched/built a vehicle that burns methane and it recovers it (at least some part) from the exhaust gases via Sabatier reaction?

I really have no idea but from the previous points I don't see it as feasible at all as a conventional internal combustion engine running on Methane.

Comment: 1) hydrogen won't be sourced from air, but from the combustion of hydrocarbons (huge amount of H2 in them) and/or electrolysis of H2O (if necessary). 2) heating of 300-400C is very easily achievable, since the exhaust gases are usually 1000C. 3) I don't understand what you mean there, there is no scientific term "heating value" that I know of. 4) of course methane will be isolated from water (not very hard process)

Comment: @sloupioc (1) Hydrogen from combustion??  (2) Do you have any idea about the size of that "easily achievable" heater? (3)Google it? (4) Everything in your engine is not "hard" and doable - the question is "is it worth it?".

Comment: @sloupioc Regarding point 3, heating value is another term for [heat of combustion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_of_combustion).

Comment: @Algo 1) you can derive H2 from natural gas with 80% efficiency. And you will recover much of it with Sabatier. 2) Who spoke about heater? The exhaust gases already have 1000C! You don't need a heater, the gases are already heated! 4) well I am looking for a PhD subject, this is not something that could be answered without extensive calculations

Comment: @sloupioc (1) That's a whole another reactor now (And it's not combustion), and again why extract hydrogen from natural gas rather than using it as a fuel already :-))?  (2) Exhaust gases are hot but hydrogen tank isn't that's why you need a heater (4) Sure, it seems like a fun project to design, anyway I don't see it as an efficient system at all :))

Comment: @sloupioc [Semin et al 2008](http://dx.doi.org/10.3844/ajeassp.2008.302.311) give an exhaust temperature for a CNG ICE of 750K. You're fighting against the laws of thermodynamics.

Answer (score 3):

Algo has given you a good answer about the detail. There is a much broader, more widely-applicable, kind of answer.

Converting any form of energy to heat introduces huge inefficiencies. It is the lowest-quality form of energy. So if you want to do any work with that energy at all, it is best to do it before it gets turned into heat, whenever possible.

Once it's in the form of heat, then the quality of the energy (what we call its *exergy*, that is it's ability to do work) depends on the difference between its temperature, and the temperature of the cold reservoir you're using as your heat sink. That's typically, but not always, ambient temperature. If you want to do any work with that heat, then you do it when the difference in temperatures is highest, and when the cold-reservoir temperature is lowest.

So you wouldn't go from heat to chemical energy to kinetic energy.

Whenever you do an energy-conversion, you lose some ability to do work - i.e. you lose some exergy. When you do non-heat to heat conversion, you lose a *lot* of exergy. So round-trip processes, where you go from, say, chemical energy (methane) to heat and then back again, are really inefficient, and you'll get much less out than you put back in.

So no, you wouldn't use the Sabatier process to power a vehicle, because that would involve:

chemical energy -[combustion]-> heat -[Sabatier]->
    chemical energy -[combustion]-> heat -[pistons]-> kinetic energy

And it really does not matter *which* conversion process is in that box that's currently marked "Sabatier": this convoluted series of conversions would not make sense, whatever that process is.

Instead, you'd just go straight from chemical energy to heat to kinetic energy, which is what combustion engines do.

**Going from methane to heat to methane is going to be very inefficient. You'd only do it in really exceptional circumstances.** I can't think of any right now, but I'm sure someone could contrive a corner-case where it made sense; e.g. some peculiar circumstance where you were able to move high-grade heat but could not move methane.

So it would be pointless to put a Sabatier (or similar) process in a methane-powered car. If you needed higher efficiency, the thing to do is to invest in vehicle efficiency: lower speeds, cleaner-burn higher-temperature engines, lighter vehicle weight, more aerodynamic profile, higher-efficiency transmission, kinetic-energy recovery systems, and so on. What you *wouldn't* do is add weight through adding inefficient unnecessary kit just to turn your heat back into fuel: just burn less fuel in the first place.